# how to create a simple activity stream?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, render, helper

I'm trying to implement a simple activity stream.

```
Given that User abc creates a post 123
And User xyz comments on 123.  
Then user abc's activity stream should look something like:
<ul>
  <li>User <a href="/users/abc">abc</a> created a post <a href="/users/abc/posts/123">123</a></li>
  <li>User <a href="/users/xyz">xyz</a> commented on post <a href="/users/abc/posts/123">123</a></li>
</ul>
```

I prefer to populate an activity model (rather than multiple queries in a controller).  I added an 'after_create' hook to both the posts and comments models to populate the activity:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord
  after_create do
    ActivityCreate(:user_id => self.user_id, :description => "created a post")
  end
end
```

I thought of storing special fields that I would need to create routes and links, such as post_id, etc, but I may have more activities I want to track later, likes, dislikes, favorites, etc, and I want a flexible way of creating activity descriptions.

So my question is, what is an efficient way of putting the link_to into the activity description?  Is there any c-style printf way of listing helpers to be evaluated later?

Sort of like this:

description = ["User ? commented on post ?", user_path(User.find(self.user_id)), post_path(Post.find(self.id))]

And then evaluate this on the template side?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea for a model to know anything about links and routes.

Comment: agreed, perhaps the activity can be better handled as a polymorphic association...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my first association about your case. Perhaps it inspires you enough :)

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  #this might be a comment or a post or something else
  belongs_to :changed_item, :polymorphic => true
  #who did it?
  belongs_to :user
  #what did he do?
  validates_presence_of :changes

  def msg
    #do fancy text generation
    if changes.new_record
      "#{user.name} created a #{changed_item.class}"
    else
      "#{user.name} changed #{changes.length} attributes of the #{changed_item.class} #{changed_item.title}"
    end
  end

  def initialize(model, user)
    #fetch changes and remember user and changed model
    self.changed_item = model
    self.user = user
    self.changes << model.changed_attributes.merge({:new_record => model.new_record?})
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save do
    #remember who to be blamed
    Activity.create(self, current_user)
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #the users activities
  has_many :activities
end
```

Comment: Just curious - In the user model, should it be has_many ':Activities' or has_many ':Activitys' or rails somehow knows the difference?

Comment: you mean singular/plural? see http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/09/inflector-rails-pluralization/ or http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization